# How to increase the height of the slicer dialog box in Power BI Desktop?

Tags: powerbi, powerbi-desktop

I have a slicer in Power BI Desktop with a height of 170 pixels and a width of 1142 pixels. The font size of the values and headers is set to 60 pixels and 13 pixels respectively.

When I select the slicer, a dialog box opens to select a value. The dialog box is a small rectangle and does not display all of the values. I want to increase the height of the dialog box so that all of the values can be displayed. Is it possible to do this using the built-in Power BI slicer visual? If not, can you recommend a slicer visual that allows me to do this?

Please have a look at the image below as well to get a clear idea of the issue.

[image: Slicer dialog box size]

Answer (score 1):

If you select your slicer and navigate to the formatting pane. Select Slicer settings and choose "dropdown".

[image: Where Format Visual is.]

Then when you select your slicer it will look like this:

[image: Dropdown slicer]